# Show that $\operatorname{rank}A+\operatorname{rank}A^m \leq n$ where $A^{m+1}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-rank

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ nilpotent matrix over a field $F$ with $A^{m+1}=0$. Show that 
>   $$\operatorname{rank}A+\operatorname{rank}A^m \leq n.$$

By FTLA, it is equivalent to 
$$ n \leq \operatorname{nullity}A+\operatorname{nullity}A^m$$
By definition, $\operatorname{nullity}A^m>0$. Thus it suffices to show that
$$\operatorname{nullity}A^r>\operatorname{nullity}A^{r+1}$$
for $0<r<m$

Comment: What is the FTLA?

Comment: Fundamental theorem of linear algebra.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that. I was trying to ask what that it state... (It is not exactly a standard name, you see)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\mathrm{nullity}(A^r)=\mathrm{nullity}(A^{r+1})$. Since $\ker(A^r)\subseteq \ker(A^{r+1})$ trivially, this implies that $\ker(A^r)=\ker(A^{r+1})$. But then
$$\ker(A^{r+2})=\{x:Ax\in \ker(A^{r+1})\}=\{x:Ax\in \ker(A^r)\}=\ker(A^{r+1})=\ker(A^r)$$
and so by induction we see that $\mathbb R^n=\ker(A^{m+1})=\ker(A^r)$, contradicting $r<m$.

Answer (score 6):

Using the Jordan canonical form, we can reduce immediately to the case where $A$ is one nilpontent Jordan block, and there the inequality is immediate :-)

Comment: (Either notice that The Jordan canonical form for nilpontent matrices can be computed over any field, or that extending the field to the algebraic closure does not change anything)

Answer (score 2):

The dimension of the kernel of $A^m$ plus the rank of $A^m$ is equal to $n$. Since $A^{m+1}$ is zero, the image of $A$ is included in the kernel of $A^m$, and in particular the rank of $A$ is less than the dimension of the kernel of $A^m$. Your formula follows.

Answer (score 1):

The image of $A^m$ is contained in the kernel of $A$, because their composition is $0$. This implies $\def\rk{\operatorname{rk}}\rk A^m\leq\dim\ker(A)$. Now rank nullity for $A$ gives $\dim\ker(A)=n-\rk A$, and substituting that gives the requested inequality.